# Handling multiple assertions and fail test if none are found

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm making a negative test case that tests if an error message pops up and then check if the message inside the modal dialog is correct. The problem is, the app has two languages: english and german so the error message can be in either of those two languages. What I have so far:

```
productsPage.CreateProduct("Test product-" + "2bd43cfd", "2bd43cfd", ".TEST Product-Buyer", "CC", "HRK", 40.94
string modalMessage = productsPage.errorMsgServiceIdTaken.Text;
try
{
   Assert.AreEqual("A product with identical service id and service provider already exists!", modalMessage);
   test.Log(Status.Pass, "Error message '" + modalMessage + "' was found inside modal dialog.");
}
catch (NUnit.Framework.AssertionException)
{
   test.Log(Status.Warning, "The modal dialog did not contain message '" + modalMessage + "'.");
}
try
{
   Assert.AreEqual("Produkt kann nicht erstellt werden! Ein Produkt mit identischer Dienst Id und Diensteanbieter ist bereits vorhanden!", modalMessage);
}
catch (NUnit.Framework.AssertionException)
{
   test.Log(Status.Warning, "The modal dialog did not contain message '" + modalMessage + "'.");
}
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   test.Log(Status.Fail, "Test execution failed: " + e.ToString());
   throw;
}
```

As you can see, I want to use two assertions because the message can be in either english or german but the problem is, I want to fail the test if none of those two asserts pass.

How should I do this?

Comment: To test a single unit of functionality you should be able to control (mock) the elements that impact it. Therefore I would look to find a way to set the language specifically to English, have a test for that, and then to German and have a test for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule of thumb is to always know what do you check in a particular test case. If the test does not clearly know which message to verify (English or German) at the particular moment you need to keep in mind that the test will be 'green' if:

1. You have an English mode on your app but the alert text is in German.  (sounds like a bug. right?)
2. You have a German mode but the alert is in English. (also does not sound correct)

I can think of 2 solutions:

1. Create 2 tests and explicitly pass the "expected language":

   ```
   @Test
   public void EnglishTest() {
       //implement logic that will start your app in English mode
       startAppInEnglishMode();
       String expectedMessage = "A product with identical service id and service provider already exists!";
       checkAlert(expectedMessage);
   }

   @Test
   public void GermanTest() {
       //implement logic that will start your app in German mode
       startAppInGermanMode();
       String expectedMessage = "Produkt kann nicht erstellt werden! Ein Produkt mit identischer Dienst Id und Diensteanbieter ist bereits vorhanden!";
       checkAlert(expectedMessage);
   } 

   public void CheckAlert(string expectedMessage) {
       string modalMessage = productsPage.errorMsgServiceIdTaken.Text;
       try {
           Assert.AreEqual(expectedMessage, modalMessage);
       } catch (NUnit.Framework.AssertionException) {
           test.Log(Status.Warning, "The modal dialog did not contain message '" + modalMessage + "'.");
       }
   }
   ```
2. Clearly define what mode is on before calling an assertion

   ```
   @Test
   public void singleTestForBothLanguages() {
       boolean isEnglishMode = isEnglishMode();
       string expectedMessage;
       if (isEnglishMode) {
           expectedMessage = "A product with identical service id and service provider already exists!";
       } else {
           expectedMessage = "Produkt kann nicht erstellt werden! Ein Produkt mit identischer Dienst Id und Diensteanbieter ist bereits vorhanden!";
       }
       checkAlert(expectedMessage);
   }

   //for example check attribute of some element (maybe a flag? or whatever makes you sure to know which mode is on now)
   public bool isEnglishMode() {
       if ( ....){
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }

   public void CheckAlert(string expectedMessage) {
       string modalMessage = productsPage.errorMsgServiceIdTaken.Text;
       try {
           Assert.AreEqual(expectedMessage, modalMessage);
       } catch (NUnit.Framework.AssertionException) {
           test.Log(Status.Warning, "The modal dialog did not contain message '" + modalMessage + "'.");
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`Assert.True`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Assert.True) method instead.

Your code will be like:

```
Assert.True(modalMessage == "A product with identical service id and service provider already exists!" || 
            modalMessage == "Produkt kann nicht erstellt werden! Ein Produkt mit identischer Dienst Id und Diensteanbieter ist bereits vorhanden!");
```

This way you'll check them both at the same time.